# SSRS DataTransform property in VS 2013 produces no output

Tags: xml, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, transform, rdl

Visual Studio 2013. Creating a report .rdl in SSRS. When I preview the .rdl output, data is present. Click the Save As icon. Select XML with report data. This exports successfully and can view xml data. Next, I create an .xsl file to transform the xml data. I specify the .xsl file in the DataTransform property field. I Preview the rdl again, and click Save As, XML with report data. I rename this .xml file with a .csv extension and Save. Open the .csv, and can view the data. This works in VS 2008 but exact same files and process does not work in VS 2013.

Others on my team are aware of this but have no resolution. Have checked .vssettings and other VS config files I could find. Nothing to indicate a setting or config that 'activates' transform in VS 2013. Internet search lists same steps as above as working in VS 2013. Any feedback on possible cause or what else to check is appreciated. I'm sure I'm leaving out needed details but don't know what else to include.